# Why does a PIM DM assert loser reply with a prune?

Tags: ip, multicast, pim

In PIM Dense Mode, why does an Assert loser send a Prune message to the winner? What is the actual motivation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a post that answers my question. For anyone that might be interested:

https://community.cisco.com/t5/routing/pim-dense-mode-duplicate-traffic/m-p/4788788

Edit:
So the answer to my question is: simply to inform the winner to stop sending traffic because it doesn't need it. Now, there are more scenarios that may appear:

- Scenario 1: **there are only the two routers on the segment**: In this case the winner receives the PIM Prune message and it stops sending the traffic.
- Scenario 2: **there is a third router (downstream) on the segment**: In which case, both the winner and the third router receive the PIM Prune message, and the third router responds to it by sending a PIM Join to override the PIM Prune sent by the loser.
- Scenario 3: **there is an IGMP receiver on the segment**: in which case the winner won't stop forwarding traffic, I assume that because of the IGMP active client.

Comment: Please add details to your answer so this post remains useful even if the linked page changes or disappears.